# Liquibase Integration Tests Using Main Database Instead of H2

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, testing, liquibase

I am trying to run integration tests in Java and I have liquibase integrated. Integration tests are running absolutely fine but the tests are referring to MySQL which is running on my localhost instead of H2, because of which my database drops first and then integration tests run. Even if I don't drop the database, it would still do modifications in main db records which is an issue in itself.

This is my ***application.properties*** file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
logging.level.liquibase=info
spring.liquibase.contexts=${CONTEXT:some-context}
```

This is my application-test.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.name=testData
spring.jmx.default-domain=jpa.sample
liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
liquibase.enabled=true
liquibase.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testData;mode:MySQL
liquibase.user=sa
liquibase.password=
spring.liquibase.drop-first=true
```

This ***liquibase.change-log*** is path to a folder created in my project's resources folder. The only thing that I would like is for my integration tests to create an H2 database and perform all operations instead of referring to the MySQL running on my localhost which my application is using.

I have used this example as a reference: https://github.com/TurgayCan/spring-boot-liquibase-example

Let me know what I can do in this matter. Thank you.

***EDIT:***

I changed my application-test.properties to the file below, but the insert statements are not working now, however the table creation/alteration queries are running and on h2 instead of MySQL

```
spring.liquibase.contexts=${CONTEXT:nontest}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:schema;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.name=schema
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Comment: I can see that you are using spring boot, did you heard about [spring-boot-testcontainers](https://github.com/Playtika/testcontainers-spring-boot/tree/develop/embedded-mysql) you can forget about H2 and execute everything in tests with mysql. It's slower than h2 to spin up but you are testing against database which you use in production.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following configuration for application-test.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```